# Creating a mean column in a dataframe dependent on other variables of the dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a code that is roughly like this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Group':['a','a','b','b','b','c','c'], 'Label':[0,1,0,1,1,0,1], 'Num':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]})
```

I would like to have a a new column that is the mean of Num, but only those with class label 1. However, this mean should be applied to all rows with label 1 only, with the rest being 0/NaN. The output should be like this:
`mean = [0,2,0,4.5,4.5,0,7]`

Also how would it be if instead of 0/Nan, you just apply that mean to all values of that group? i.e.
`mean = [2,2,4.5,4.5,4.5,7,7]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

##### NaNs/0

If NaNs are OK, just slice before applying a `groupby`+`mean`:

```
df['mean'] = df[df['Label'].eq(1)].groupby('Group')['Num'].transform('mean')
```

output:

```
  Group  Label  Num  mean
0     a      0    1   NaN
1     a      1    2   2.0
2     b      0    3   NaN
3     b      1    4   4.5
4     b      1    5   4.5
5     c      0    6   NaN
6     c      1    7   7.0
```

If you prefer 0, you can `fillna(0)`

##### output on all rows

To get the output on all rows.

`mask` the values in Num when Label is 1 to change them into NaNs, `groupby` the Group values and `transform` all rows with the `mean` of the group.

```
df['mean'] = (df['Num'].mask(df['Label'].ne(1))
                       .groupby(df['Group']).transform('mean'))
```

output:

```
  Group  Label  Num  mean
0     a      0    1   2.0
1     a      1    2   2.0
2     b      0    3   4.5
3     b      1    4   4.5
4     b      1    5   4.5
5     c      0    6   7.0
6     c      1    7   7.0
```

Comment: This is awesome and was quite fast, but could you please explain a bit how the pandas is working?

Comment: @JohnCollins I added a short summary, but please let me know what you don't understand

Comment: It's interesting how masking an inverse is used... why is that necessary? No worries if you don't have time to explain, or, at least for me (might help the OP), I'll figure it out eventually, looking at pandas docs now...

Comment: @JohnCollins actually, I should have use `where(condition)` here instead of the `mask(~condition)`, I just thought `mask` is better in terms or natural language. Or `mask(df['Label'].ne(1))`, actually I'll change to that ;)

Comment: Actually yeah I think it made more sense natural language wise the first way because we're concerned with _those that do equal to 1_, but either way really is quite the same. I think yeah your final edit makes it more "pythonic" looking, esp in case you don't know what "~" does